# how to rename files to sub directory

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to rename  all my .wav files in my sub directory with a tag of sub directory they are present in. Fox example 
**directory/sub-directory1/ 1_1.wav** to **directory/sub-directory1/ sdir1_1.wav** . I know how to rename files in python but I cannot loop through the subdirectory and then add the tag.
although the code below works to align sub dir and files but it wont loop through all the files because `for dire in dirs:` will not work if the files are more than the dirs

```
 import os

    rootdir = r'C:\Users\test'

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):

        for dire in dirs:
          for file in files:
           filepath = subdir+os.sep+file

           if filepath.endswith('.wav'):
             print (dire+ file)
```

Comment: `os.walk` doesn't work that way. the loops on files & dirs must not be nested. Can you be more specific on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a folder which has a dozen of sub folders. In all the sub folders there are some .wav (files). These .wav files are named randomly and are not systematic. So, what I want to do is rename these files with the name of the sub directory and increment for example : subdir1.wav, subdir2.wav and so on. Basically trying to add the reference of the subdirectory to the wave file. I hope I am clear ?

Comment: for this I need to loop through the sub directory and rename the files and then go to another sub directory and rename those files and so on.

Comment: Did you mean **sub-directory2/ 1.wav** to **sub-directory2/ sdir2_1.wav**? Please re-read your question and edit it for more clarity.

Comment: @elena I'm sorry it was just an example. I hope I could get some logic to do so.

Comment: Why don't you just create a dict, in which the key would be the dirname and as a value would be the files. Then you could loop through the dict and rename the files.

Comment: @choman I know it's an example, but it confuses people when they try to help. First you are saying that you want to rename the filenames, then in your example you are also renaming the directories. Do you get my point?

Comment: Ah okay! Yes I fixed it. the sub directory is dynamic and so are the wav files . I may add more files or delete them. hence, I want to work this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this and it works.

```
import shutil
import os
from glob import glob

# Define your source folder.
source_dir = 'F:\\Test\\in\\'
# Define your target folder.
target_dir = 'F:\\Test\\out\\'
# Define the file extension you want to search for.
file_ext = '*.mp4'
# use glob to create a list of files in your source DIR with teh desired extension.
file_check = glob(source_dir + file_ext)


# For each item in file_check shuttle will copy teh source file and write it renamed to your target location.
for i in file_check:

    shutil.copy(i, target_dir + 'dir_out_' + os.path.basename(i)) 
    #os.path.basename gives us just the filename and extension minus the absolute path.
    #i,e test123456.mp4
```

Here are the contents of the target dir:

```
F:\Test\out\dir_out_test_10.mp4
F:\Test\out\dir_out_test_2.mp4
F:\Test\out\dir_out_test_3.mp4
F:\Test\out\dir_out_test_4.mp4
F:\Test\out\dir_out_test_5.mp4
F:\Test\out\dir_out_test_6.mp4
F:\Test\out\dir_out_test_7.mp4
F:\Test\out\dir_out_test_8.mp4
F:\Test\out\dir_out_test_9.mp4
```

Check out the [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shutil.html) and [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html) if you want to do a file system move instead of a copy use `shutil.move()` instead of `shutil.copy()`.

**EDIT:**

Python 3.5+

Here is how to find all files in a root DIR:

```
glob('F:\\test\\**\\*.mp4', recursive=True)
```

This will find all the files the root DIR and sub folders, then you can use the shutil method above to do with them what you want.

Comment: Thanx for helping out. In your code `source_dir = 'F:\\Test\\in\\'` is pointing to just one folder so all the .wav files has to be in this folder but in my case there are numerous sub folders under `'F:\\Test\\in\\'` like `'F:\\Test\\in\\sub_folder1'`, `'F:\\Test\\in\\sub_folder2'` etc. There fore I need to loop inside the folders to find sub folders. I am not sure if your answer meets my requirement or I may have failed to understand. Please explain if it can be achieved through glob ? i.e iterate through sub folders ?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I was able to achieve the result.

```
 import os

    rootdir = r'C:\Users\test'

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):

        for file in filenames:
         filepath = dirpath +os.sep+file
         if filepath.endswith('wav'):
                 # split directory filepath
                 split_dirpath = dirpath.split(os.sep)
                 # take the name of the last directory which I want to tag
                 dir_tag = (split_dirpath[-1])
                 # wasn't necessary to split the extension, still....
                 f_name, f_ext = (os.path.splitext(file))
                 # add the tag of the sub dir
                 f_name= dir_tag +'_'+ f_name
                 # create the new file name
                 new_name = f_name +f_ext
                 print(new_name)
                 os.rename(filepath,dirpath+os.sep+new_name)
```